# Outliers in OLS

Tags: regression, least-squares, outliers

I'm running OLS regression in stata with 5-6 IVs (all dummy variables) and a DV (continuous). Does it make sense to check for outliers (e.g., I can't run scatter dv x1 x2) in this case?
Also, is it necessary to check for outliers in the DV? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you did check for outliers and found one, what would that mean? What would you do with that information?

Comment: In one case, I have variable whose lowest values were about 50 in early 1950s and then went up to about 2000 in early 2000s. I felt that this didn't warrant removing any values as it just reflected change over time in the variable. I was wondering if this makes sense? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't *exactly* run a scatter plot, you can do strip plots, or parallel box plots. (Use the former if N is small, the latter if it is large, or do both). These are roughly equivalent to a scatter. You could do one for each independent variable.

Also, if you do the regression in R or SAS (or maybe other programs) the program will give you plots. E.g in R:

```
set.seed(1234)

x1 <- c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50))
y <- c(rnorm(50, 0, 1), rnorm(49, 2, 1), 20) #Outlier on the DV

m1 <- lm(y~x1)
plot(m1)
```

Does indeed show outliers. (I kept it simple with only one IV, but the same is true with more than one).

Another question is what about "outliers" among all the IVs?  That is, while it's hard to be an outlier on a single categorical variable, it's easy to be one on a combination.

Being a widow isn't odd. Being under 18 years old isn't odd. Being a widow who is under 18 years old is very odd indeed. Whether that odd person affects the regression will depend (I think) on the value of Y for that person, but it's good to know about such oddities, if only to correct them.